# Does `select_for_update()` method combine with `filter()` method & chain with `update()` method explicitly lock records in table?

Tags: django, postgresql

I use `select_for_update()` method to lock record in table for updating. The https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update Django 4.2 documentation states that "when the queryset is evaluated, all matching records will be locked until the end of the transaction block". When I use `select_for_update()` method chain with `filter()` method & `update()` method to update the queryset in one line of code, I figure out that the 'SELECT ... FOR UPDATE' exists in the SQL code (I am using Postgresql) without evaluating. So does my code explicitly lock records without evaluating the queryset when combining `select_for_update()` method with `filter()` method?

Here is my testing function:

```
def testing_select_for_update():
    accounting_period_obj = AccoutingPeriod.objects.latest('id')
    product = Product.objects.get(name='Cebraton')

    with transaction.atomic():
        accounting_period_inventory_obj =  AccountingPeriodInventory.objects.select_related('accounting_period_id', 'product_id').select_for_update().filter(
            accounting_period_id=accounting_period_obj,
            product_id__name=product.name
        )
        accounting_period_inventory_obj.update(starting_inventory=10)

    connection_queries = connection.queries
    for connection_query in connection_queries:
        print(connection_query)
```

The SQL code in the transaction block is:
`{'sql': 'UPDATE "major_features_accountingperiodinventory" SET "starting_inventory" = 10 WHERE "major_features_accountingperiodinventory"."id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "major_features_accountingperiodinventory" U0 INNER JOIN "major_features_product" U2 ON (U0."product_id_id" = U2."sku") WHERE (U0."accounting_period_id_id" = 4 AND U2."name" = \'Cebraton\') FOR UPDATE)', 'time': '0.000'}`